# Injective Function: Finite Codomain and Finite Domain

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $g:X → Y$ is an injective function. If $Y$ is ﬁnite, then $X$ is ﬁnite.

I believe this is true but I'm having some significant problems writing a proof.

So far I have,

Assume $g:X → Y$ is an injective function and let Y be finite.

Then for each $x \in X$, there is a unique $Y$ associated with x by a function $g.$

From there I am just not sure where to go.

Comment: HINT: what does it mean for a set to be finite? And, can you show that a subset of a finite set is finite?

Answer (score 1):

If $Y$ is finite, there exists an $n \in \Bbb N$ so that $Y$ is equinumerous with $A= \{i \in \Bbb N:i \le n \}$

Also $g(X) \subset Y$ and thus it can't have more elements than $Y$, so there exists an $m \in \Bbb N$ so that $m \le n$ and $g(X)$ is equinumerous with $B= \{i \in \Bbb N:i \le m \}$

Now, $g:X \to g(X)$ is a bijection and therefore $X$ is equinumerous with $g(X)$ and as a result with $B$. This means that $X$ is finite